# How to maintain backstack of fragment in Navigation Drawer?

Tags: java, android

I have taken one activity and with activity I have attached navigation drawer and the home fragment. In that navigation drawer there is a option of "Contact Us". When user click on that option a fragment gets open. But I am not able to maintain the stack of that. means when I am on contact us fragment then using navigation drawer again click on contact us it overlaps previous one. I have to press back button 2 times to go on home fragment. Please Help me how to maintain back stack for this. Here is my code..

```
navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
                int id = item.getItemId();
                switch (id) {

                    case R.id.rate:

                        Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=" + getPackageName());
                        Intent myAppLinkToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                        try {
                            startActivity(myAppLinkToMarket);
                        } catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Unable to find source market app!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                        break;


                    case R.id.contact_us:

                        FragmentTransaction transaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                        transaction.add(R.id.fragment_container_dashboard, ContactUsFragment.newInstance());
                        transaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        transaction.commit();
                        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);


                        break;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

After this code I use this to maintain back stack:

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
            getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
        }

        else new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to exit?")
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                        Dashboard.super.onBackPressed();
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton("No", null)
                .show();
    }
```

But the issue is It's show exit dialogue on contact us fragment when ever I press back button. But I want firstly I reach to home fragment and after that If I press back button then it show exit dialogue.

Comment: navigation drawer is in activity. so when you switch to fragment b you don't need navigation drawer you can hide the navigation drawer. or you can check if navigation drawer item shown is the same one that you clicked and close the drawer instead of add the fragment

Comment: Each time you select contact us from the drawer, you are adding a brand new instance of the contact us fragment to the backstack. So when you click it multiple times, you actually are adding multiple fragments. Rather than calling `transaction.add()` try using `transaction.replace()`. Or like mentioned above, simply do not recreate the fragment if you do not need to when selecting the item from the drawer.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by adding this in the onCreate method.

```
getSupportFragmentManager().addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onBackStackChanged() {
            if(getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() == 0){
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_UNLOCKED);
                menuToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(true);
                // your dialog
            }else{
                drawer.setDrawerLockMode(DrawerLayout.LOCK_MODE_LOCKED_CLOSED);
                menuToggle.setDrawerIndicatorEnabled(false);
                // remove to your previous fragment
            }
        }
    });
```